# Does any undirected graph admits a doubly stochastic matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph, can we always find a way to assign weights to every edge so that the adjacent matrix is double stochastic matrix?

(edit: We allow the matrix has positive element on (i,i), so strictly speaking, it is not an adjacent matrix)

The background is about distributed optimization. We can see each node as a computer, and they want to exchange information(like gradients or parameters) via edges in the connected graph to solve an optimization problem, for example, a machine learning problem. So, there is a weight matrix W, whose (i,j) element is the weight of information sent from node i to node j. Because node i can use its own information, so diagonal elements of W should be positive. The question is can we always find a doubly stochastic matrix W.

Comment: Interesting question! 
And/but I hesitate to upvote as long as you do not give more flesh to the bones, e.g., what are/were your attempts towards a solution? In which context did it arise?

Comment: Sure, I want to ask this question because I have seen a proof of disributed optimization where every node exchanges information to get a consensus. The element (i,j) of the matrix is the weight of information from node i to node j. And of course node i can send information to itself, so we allow the diagonal elements to be positive. If the matrix is doubly stochastic, the proof can be very simple. So I am curious that if it exists for any connected undirected graph.

Comment: Check the formula for metropolis hastings weights. They provide a simple way to construct weights corresponding to the graph using node degrees to give a doubly stochastic matrix. Since you are studying consensus algorithms, here is a reference which hopefully helps you: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/avg_metropolis.pdf

Comment: @user143234 Thanks a lot for the reference!

Comment: @Hanno Thanks for your comment! I've added the background information about this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, consider the path of length $3$, which has adjacency matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&0}.
$$
In order for the first row to have a sum of $1$, the edge $(1,2)$ must have weight $1$. However, in order for the second row to have a sum of $1$ (and for the edge $(2,3)$ to have a non-zero weight), the edge $(1,2)$ must have weight less than $1$.

---

That said, if we can give distinct weights to the edge in each direction, then we can at least produce a row-stochastic matrix in the form of the transition matrix corresponding to a simple random walk over the graph. In particular, this means that the (directed) edge $i \to j$ is given the weight $\frac 1{i}$. For the path of length $3$, this gives us the matrix
$$
P = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\1/2&0&1/2\\0&1&0}.
$$

---

For the question as I now understand it, the answer is yes. It suffices to assign weights as follows:

Let $d$ denote the degree of the graph (i.e. the maximal vertex degree). Let $d_i$ denote the degree of vertex $i$. It suffices to assign the weight $\frac 1{d}$ to all off-diagonal entries (i.e. to all non-loop edges) and weight $\frac{d-d_i}{d}$ to the $i$th diagonal entry (i.e. the loop on the $i$th vertex).

That is, let $D$ denote the [degree matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_matrix), the diagonal matrix whose $i$th diagonal entry is the degree of the $i$th vertex. Then the matrix
$
\frac 1d [dI + A - D]
$
is doubly stochastic.

We could also write this as $\frac 1d[dI - L]$, where $L$ denotes the [graph Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix).

Comment: Sorry for my misrepresentation. The matrix in question is not adjacent matrix. We allow element (i,i) to be positive. For example, for path of length 3, matrix \begin{pmatrix} 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\ 1/3 & 2/3 & 0\\ 1/3 & 0 & 2/3 \end{pmatrix} is ok.

Comment: @efsdfmo12 See my latest edit.

Comment: @BenGrossmann If the matrix is an adjacency matrix (no self weights exist, $A_{ii} = 0$), you have given an example that can not be transformed into a doubly stochastic matrix (DSM) through weight assigning. I am wondering under which condition, an adjacency matrix can be transformed into a DSM, while this is impossible in other scenarios? Is there any analysis of this problem?

Comment: @Yuejiang_Li I don't know of any such analysis